# Yii2 composer installed library does not recognized by namespaces

Tags: php, yii2, namespaces, odata

I am trying to deploy a Yii2 app that consumes OData services. But I am having a bit problem: I choose https://github.com/saintsystems/odata-client-php (OData Client library from SaintSystems), I installed with composer and there was no complain. But when I use instantiate the objects it says:

```
$odataClient = new ODataClient($odataServiceUrl);
```

Then

```
    Error
Class 'app\controllers\ODataClient' not found
```

And if

```
$odataClient = new \SaintSystems\OData\ODataClient($odataServiceUrl);
```

Then it complains with:

```
Call to undefined method SaintSystems\OData\Query\Builder::post()
```

So I think Yii 2 is not recognizing the namespaces or composer does not set them up correctly. How could I make yii2 take this namespace and I deploy successfully with this library.

Thank you all!

Comment: You tried putting `use SaintSystems\OData;` before your Class statement and using like `$odataClient = new ODataClient($odataServiceUrl);`? If you're loading Yii2 via composer, it should know how to reference the files.

Comment: It says it does not find ODataclient() ;( ... So if I put SaintSystems\OData\ODataClient($odataServiceUrl); it works but when that function tries to get another one inside of the class it tells that it cannot be found again...